# C++ read memory address with pointer+offset

Tags: c++, memory, process

I am trying to read an address of a process which should be the number 20. I determined this address was located at the dll base offset + a number with an offset of 10. I am using

```
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, &number, sizeof(number), 0);
```

to read a specific address. My question is how do I correctly search for the address located at "57B86F68" + the 10 offset?

Comment: Remember unless you disabled it you probably have to deal with ASLR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you looking for the address `0x57b86f68 + 10` or are you looking for the address (or some other kind of value) stored at that location? Either way, you shouldn't need to *search* for anything.

Comment: @drescherjm, I made sure to grab the base address through code so that isn't a problem as far as I am aware of.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry for the confusion, so there is a static pointer at a certain location. I found this location, it points to an address which that address with the offset of 10 is the value I am looking to read. I am unsure of how I can do this though.

For example, I am reading address a, which points to b. I am than trying to get the value of b + 10, would there be a simple way to do this?

Comment: you have the address and you have the offset ... now everything is OK so what is the problem????

Comment: It's not working, it doesn't return the correct number. I am sending it 
` ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)(baseaddress + address), &testNum, sizeof(testNum), 0); `
Which I thought would set testNum to the address the pointer points to. 
Than I send 
` ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)(testNum + 0x10), &count, sizeof(count), 0) `
which returns something completely wrong like "-9.25596e+61"

Comment: @Jack After call of `ReadProcessMemory` call `GetLastError` to get more information about the reason of `ReadProcessMemory` failure. Check your `OpenProcess` flags, `PROCESS_VM_READ ` also should be there.

Comment: @Nikita that solved it. Thank you! I was using a different flag for the OpenProcess which appears to have been messing it up.

Comment: @Jack Nice to hear. Seems you can upvote my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the data from handle if your `phandle` is a process handle with PROCESS_VM_READ access granted:

```
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)(0x57B86F68 + 0x10), &number, sizeof(number), 0);
```

To get proper access rights for the process handle check your `OpenProcess` flags, `PROCESS_VM_READ` should be there.

If it still not working things are much more complex. You should translate your [virtual address to physical address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366602/how-to-translate-a-virtual-memory-address-to-a-physical-address) and after that get direct access to the memory via [kernel mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403610/how-do-you-read-directly-from-physical-memory).